# c# send udp and get response

Tags: c#, udp

I'm trying to create a little program in c# to deal with the xiaomi smart home api. 
[Api translation](https://github.com/illxi/lumi-gateway-local-api/blob/master/device_discover.md)

I'm stuck at the beginning. I don't achieve to send {"cmd" : "get_id_list"} to the gateway and receive the response.

I'm trying to use this code to send but I've got nothong in response :

```
    string i = "{\"cmd\" : \"get_id_list\"}";
    UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.112"), 9898);
    Byte[] buffer = null;
    buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(i.ToString());
    client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, ep);
    byte[] b2 = client.Receive(ref ep);
    string str2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b2, 0, b2.Length);
```

192.168.1.112 is my gateway ip adress.

Here a screenshot of packet senders software on windows : [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6MO3.jpg)

We can see that the gateway reply to me the right informations.

So how to get this reply whatever the response port ?

thank for your help

Comment: More info from previous posting.  Doesn't make sense the send and receive ports are different for same connection.  It looks like Broadcast udp may be used but still need protocol to help futher.  Where did you get the data from?  Did you use a sniffer?  You need to use connect method before you can send/receive which is missing in posted code.

Comment: The msdn example are real poor. Often are confusing.  I can see you copied code from msdn.  Just add connect after IPEndPoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jdweng suggests, you need to use a Connect() method on your UDP client, or it won't listen for responses. You can either do this, or use two separate UdpClients, one to send and one to receive.

```
string i = "{\"cmd\" : \"get_id_list\"}";
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.112"), 9898));

Byte[] buffer = null;
buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(i.ToString());
client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, ep);
byte[] b2 = client.Receive(ref ep);
string str2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b2, 0, b2.Length);
```